# Issue with storing variables to array in C

Tags: arrays, c

I have small issue with storing recalculated values to a second array, namely I have array of prices, and a function to calculate and apply discounts to them, but for some reason they dont get stored in this `discountArray`, because it returns **the regular `priceArray` values**:

```
int discountArr[lengthArray];
int discount, i;            
discount = GetIntInRange(MIN_DISC, MAX_DISC);
for (i = 0; i < lengthArray; i++)
{
    discountArr[i] = DiscountCalc(discount, priceArray[i]);
}
```

The supporting function #1 (for getting disc percentage in between certain range):

```
int GetIntInRange(int min, int max)
{
    int num;
    do
    {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if (num < min || num > max)
            printf("\nInput must be in between %d and %d\n", min, max);
            break;
    } while (num < min || num > max);
    return num;
}
```

Function #2 the calculation (seemingly no problems with this one):

```
int DiscountCalc(int discountPercent, int regPrice)
{
    int newPrice;
    newPrice = regPrice * ( 1 - (discountPercent / 100));
    return newPrice;
}
```

Can anyone please point out the mistake to me?

Comment: `discountPercent / 100` - this is an integer division. Will be zero for any reasonable discount percentage.

Comment: thanks!! didnt notice. :)